# Enable to close the save address popup in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm unable to close save address popup in chrome and it is affecting my test case.
I'm using chrome versio 114.0.5735.110 and chrome driver version 114.0.5735.90.
I tried using chrome option, My code is as below

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking"); 
options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
options.addArguments("--disable-infobars");
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions"); 
options.addArguments("--disable-save-password-bubble");
```

Can anyone suggest me some way to disable the popup.